# Validar button con AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android-studio, validación, botón

Estoy queriendo validar mi app haciendo que el botón esté invisible hasta que los datos correspondientes sean llenados por lo que he estado buscando como validar que el AutoCompleteTextView sea llenado y con eso comprobar el botón

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Inflar el Layout con el Fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_in, container, false);

    fillFields(view);
    validateButton(view);
    return view;
}

private void validateButton(View view){
    Button check_in_buttom = view.findViewById(R.id.check_in_button);
    check_in_buttom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    AutoCompleteTextView brand = view.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_brand);

    if (brand.isSelected()){
        check_in_buttom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        check_in_buttom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}


//Metodo para llenar los autoCompleteTextView
private void fillFields(View view){
    AutoCompleteTextView auto_complete_brand = view.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_brand);
    AutoCompleteTextView auto_complete_year = view.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_year);
    AutoCompleteTextView auto_complete_model = view.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_model);
    AutoCompleteTextView auto_complete_color = view.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_color);
    AutoCompleteTextView auto_complete_code = view.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_code);

    //Brand
    String[] brands = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_brands);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterBrands = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireContext(), R.layout.spinner_item , brands);
    auto_complete_brand.setAdapter(adapterBrands);
}
```

**strings.xml**

> Aquí tengo dos datos de prueba nada más pero ya con que me funcione
> una vez lo puedo implementar en los demás lados.

```
<!-- Brands -->
    <string-array name="array_brands">
        <item>Toyota</item>
        <item>Honda</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: Por cierto he visto que realizas preguntas y no comentas si las respuestas son correctas o no, simplemente las eliminas, te sugiero revisar [tour] y [ask], saludos.

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta para las próximas publicaciones. Y referente a esta pregunta ¿Algún comentario?

Comment: "hasta que los datos correspondientes sean llenados", te refieres cuando el AutoCompleteTextView tiene un valor seleccionado?. El método fillFields() llena el AutoCompleteTextView ? si es así podrías agregarlo por favor

Comment: Eso es correcto, ya te he dejado el método fillfields() en la publicación